# Adding tags to ECS Service - InvalidParameterException

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a fully working Fargate application up and running in AWS. I went back to add tags to all my resources to better monitor costs in a microservice architecture. Upon adding tags to my aws_ecs_service resource, I got the following exception when running `terraform apply`:

```
aws_ecs_service.main: error tagging ECS Cluster (arn:aws:ecs:*region*:*account_number*:service/*service_name*): InvalidParameterException: Long arn format must be used for tagging operations
```

After some research, I found that on November 15, AWS introduced a new ARN and ID format: https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/faqs/#Transition_to_new_ARN_and_ID_format

I know that I need to apply the settings to the IAM Role that I have assigned to my service, but I can't figure out how. Here is a link to the AWS docs for account settings: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_Setting.html

Below is a snippet of the ecs service resource as well as the task definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app" {
  family                   = "${var.app_name}"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = "${var.app_cpu}"
  memory                   = "${var.app_memory}"
  execution_role_arn       = "${var.execution_role_arn}"
  task_role_arn            = "${var.task_role_arn}"

  tags {
    Name        = "${var.app_name}-ecs-task-definition-${var.environment}"
    Service     = "${var.app_name}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
    Cost_Center = "${var.tag_cost_center}"
    Cost_Code   = "${var.tag_cost_code}"
  }

  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
[
  {
    "cpu": ${var.app_cpu},
    "image": "${var.app_image}",
    "memory": ${var.app_memory},
    "name": "${var.app_name}",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "stash-${var.app_name}",
        "awslogs-region": "${var.aws_region}",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "${var.app_name}"
      }
    },
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": ${var.app_port},
        "hostPort": ${var.app_port}
      }
    ]
  }
]
DEFINITION
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "main" {
  name            = "${var.app_name}-service"
  cluster         = "${var.cluster_id}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.app.arn}"
  desired_count   = "1"
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"

  network_configuration {
    security_groups = ["${var.security_groups}"]
    subnets         = ["${var.subnets}"]
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${var.target_group_arn}"
    container_name   = "${var.app_name}"
    container_port   = "${var.app_port}"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["desired_count"]
  }

  tags {
    Name        = "${var.app_name}-ecs-service-${var.environment}"
    Service     = "${var.app_name}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
    Cost_Center = "${var.tag_cost_center}"
    Cost_Code   = "${var.tag_cost_code}"
  }
}
```

Here is a look into my security resource:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "task_role" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-task-${var.environment}"

  assume_role_policy = <<END
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
END
}
```

I am using terraform version 0.11.8.

Answer (score 8):

Since you mentioned `terraform`, let me add this (I am also using terraform and hit a very similar problem).  You can use AWS CLI, with the ECS subcommand `put-account-setting` to set the three `LongArnFormat`'s

```
aws ecs put-account-setting --name containerInstanceLongArnFormat --value enabled --region _yourRegion_
aws ecs put-account-setting --name serviceLongArnFormat           --value enabled --region _yourRegion_
aws ecs put-account-setting --name taskLongArnFormat              --value enabled --region _yourRegion_
```

Reference: [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/ecs-resource-ids.html#ecs-modifying_longer_id_settings)

Comment: on a related note: if you're getting `aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice` when trying to execute these, upgrade your awscli

Answer (score 5):

Per the [online documentation for opting in](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-your-amazon-ecs-deployment-to-the-new-arn-and-resource-id-format-2/) to the new ARN format, you'll need Root account access to opt-in for a specific IAM role.

The steps detailed in the above link state you should

- Create an IAM role for your cluster (you have done this)
- Log in as root
- Head to the [opt in page](http://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home#/clusters/optIn/resourceIdArnFormat) and select that IAM role to opt in
- Hopefully profit!

Note that you can also opt-in for your entire account, until Jan 2020 at which point this change will become mandatory.

Comment: Hey James, I understand your point. But the problem statement here is for the Fargate based ECS, not the EC2 based ECS services. Is this process valid for those as well?

Comment: @nitin194 I believe the process applies to all ECS types, though if I understand the AWS timeline correctly the new ID format should now be applied universally to all accounts by AWS. According to the link specified in the question, "Through the end of December 2019, new ARNs/IDs will be available for opt-in via APIs and the ECS Console. All accounts can opt-in and out as needed for testing. Starting on January 1, 2020, the option to switch formats will no longer be available, and newly-created ECS resources will all receive the new ARNs and ID formats."